# RESTful Routing with Express.js: Why does Express's res.redirect alter the location of static assets?

Tags: node.js, express, restful-url

This is almost surely a conceptual misunderstanding on my own part.  Can somebody please help me to understand where I am going wrong here?

I would really like to adhere to RESTful routing practices in my Express.js project.  I am using EJS and I am serving static assets with the standard ...

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Although the Express doc's do not appear to explicitly mention res.redirect to routes (rather than file paths), it works and I am operating under the assumption that this is standard practice.  And, so long as the depth of the route pathname is just one (like /range, but not like /range/edit), everything with this works just fine.

But, of course, an actual RESTful routing practice involves more depth than this ...

- ACTION - ROUTE - HTTP VERB
- list - /users - GET
- show - /users/1 - GET
- edit - /users/1/edit - GET
- new - /users/new - GET
- create - /users - POST
- update - /users/1 - PATCH
- delete - /users/1 - DELETE

res.redirect() is excellent for RESTful paths insofar as the URL pathname comes up correct.

However, when I use Express to res.redirect to a path with two or more levels of depth -- such as /users/new -- my EJS file no longer finds my static assets.  Instead of looking in the correct directory, it adds a `/users/` subdirectory into the static file path.

I am observing from the Google searches that this must be the expected behavior.

How would a person implement a RESTful routing system while still using redirects and EJS with Express.js?

Or, if I'm only supposed to be using redirects to navigate paths instead of routes, then what is the proper way to set up these RESTful routes?

I notice that without the use of res.redirect, the tendency is towards a lot of code duplication throughout my routes, with multiple res.render's basically doing the same thing, and the added problem of the URL pathname reflecting whatever route the render originated from (rather than the RESTful route I'd prefer).  Sub-optimal.

I must be missing something fundamental here ...

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Static routes are for serving static assets from the file system, period.  Restful routes should be completely different route definitions and paths that are served by code, not out of the file system.  It sounds like you're trying to mix the two.  `res.redirect()` should not be needed for  either.  If multiple `res.render()` operations are doing the same thing, then create common functions that you can call from multiple routes.  If multiple routes are doing the same thing, then create common route handlers.

Comment: If multiple route definitions are identical, then use a more complicated route definition to include multiple routes in the same handler.  This is coding.  You still have to think and use normal coding techniques to avoid duplicating code.